# Create new Leaflet control in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I'm using [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/), [leaflet-editable](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.Editable) and Angular in a project. I want to create controls for drawing a multi polygon on the map (Much like the given example on the github page). My code in my component is as follows:

```
import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-editable';

...

this.map = L.map('map', {editable: true}).setView([-0.163360, 13.053125], 3).addLayer(osm);
L.NewPolygonControl = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    position: 'topleft'
  },
  onAdd: function (map) {
    const container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control leaflet-bar'),
      link = L.DomUtil.create('a', '', container);
    link.title = 'Create a new polygon';
    link.innerHTML = '▱';
    L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
      .on(link, 'click', function () {
        map.editTools.startPolygon();
      });
    container.style.display = 'block';
    map.editTools.on('editable:enabled', function (e) {
      container.style.display = 'none';
    });
    map.editTools.on('editable:disable', function (e) {
      container.style.display = 'block';
    });
    map.editTools.on('editable:drawing:move', function (e) {

    });
    return container;
  }
});
L.AddPolygonShapeControl = L.Control.extend({
  options: {
    position: 'topleft'
  },
  onAdd: function (map) {
    const container = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'leaflet-control leaflet-bar'),
      link = L.DomUtil.create('a', '', container);
    link.title = 'Create a new polygon';
    link.innerHTML = '▱▱';
    L.DomEvent.on(link, 'click', L.DomEvent.stop)
      .on(link, 'click', function () {
        if (!map.editTools.currentPolygon) return;
        map.editTools.currentPolygon.editor.newShape();
      });
    container.style.display = 'none';
    map.editTools.on('editable:enabled', function (e) {
      container.style.display = 'block';
    });
    map.editTools.on('editable:disable', function (e) {
      container.style.display = 'none';
    });
    return container;
  }
});
this.map.addControl(new L.NewPolygonControl());
this.map.addControl(new L.AddPolygonShapeControl());
```

The controls work fine however, I get an error message after the compile stating the following:

```
ERROR in src/app/pages/countryEdit/country/country.component.ts(84,7):         
error TS2339: Property 'NewPolygonControl' does not exist on type         
'typeof L'.
src/app/pages/countryEdit/country/country.component.ts(110,7): error 
TS2339: Property 'AddPolygonShapeControl' does not exist on type 
'typeof L'.
src/app/pages/countryEdit/country/country.component.ts(134,31): error 
TS2339: Property 'NewPolygonControl' does not exist on type 'typeof 
L'.
src/app/pages/countryEdit/country/country.component.ts(135,31): error 
TS2339: Property 'AddPolygonShapeControl' does not exist on type 
'typeof L'.
```

My knowledge is of angular and typescript are still limited and I don't know how to fix this compile error. I have added types for leaflet and leaflet-editable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming here with the same problem. I just created a new variable instead of creating a new property on L. So instead of `L.NewControl = 'bla bla'` I just wrote `const newControl = 'bla bla'`. I used the new variable just as I would the `L.NewControl` and everything worked fine with no compile errors.

Comment: Hi, i am facing same issue , can you share working example here?Thanks!

Comment: Hi Suraj, I'll try to put one up as soon as possible

Comment: Thanks @MarkusAfricanus, i got the solution.